# What/how should a .php script return to a shell script to represent success/error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following scenario:

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php5 -f /path/file.php && echo 'success';
```

What should `file.php` return to **continue** (&&) or to **break** the `script.sh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It MUST return `0` in case of success and can choose an exit code between `1` and `255` in case of error. This is specified in [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX)

Explanation for PHP:

In PHP you are required to make sure to handle all logical errors and call explicitly:

```
exit(1); // or another error code, but different from 0
```

... in order to return an application error. When a syntax error or another type of fatal error occurs, `php` will return `255` which is also unequal to `0`.

In all other cases, meaning you either you:

- don't call `exit()` or it's alias `die()` at all
- call `exit()` or it's alias `die()` with a string argument

PHP will return with `0`. Of course you are free to call explicitly `exit(0);` for better readability.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept! Maybe for future visitors it would be good to note what strings do ('1', '0', '5') and what other types do (NULL, TRUE, FALSE or empty ('')).

Comment: yeah, give me a minute.